# How to export the data returned from snap.data() into a GCP bucket?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get a Firestore export of only new documents being added to my Firestore sub collection: reviews. The below .onCreate method logs the new fields whenever I create a new document. However, I want to export only the new documents to my GCP bucket to import it later to a BigQuery table. Any idea how I can achieve this?

**Cloud Function code:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    
    exports.createUser = functions.firestore
        .document('vision_data/{id}/reviews/{reviewsId}')
        .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      
        console.log(snap.data());
        
        return null;
        
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [export the specific collection to Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_specific_collections) and then [load the data in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore) afterwards. Notice that you'll simply need to run a command like the following:

```
gcloud firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME] --collection-ids=[COLLECTION_ID_1],[COLLECTION_ID_2]
```

Or you could write the data stored in `snap.data()` in a file and afterwards use the Client Library to upload the Data to Cloud Storage [using the methods describe here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files).

Comment: I am very new to this environment and really struggling with coding cloud functions. Could you please give me an example on how I can write snap.data() to a file? @Daniel Ocando

Comment: snap.data() gives me the fields and their values within the new documents. However, i want to bring out an export.metadata kind of file (the one which gets generated when we execute the gcloud firestore export command). the gcloud firestore export takes a full export of my collections, but i want to take incremental exports on daily basis. How do i achieve that? Can the gcloud firestore export command be modified in some way to just take exports of new documents being added to my collections? @Daniel Ocando